# HTML/CSS - Sentence with no spaces exit outside div

Tags: html, css, space

**HTML:**

```
<div> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div {
    width: 150px;
    border: 1px solid red
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/B93XB/

**QUESTION:** What would be solution for this?

Comment: try to use `overflow:auto`

Comment: I don't need scroll, but thanks for trying to help me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `word-break:break-all`

Also add `display:inline-block`

```
div {
    width: 150px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    background:red;
    word-break:break-all;
    display:inline-block
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/B93XB/5/)**

Comment: Perfect! Didn't know about word-break

Comment: tnx I really didnt know about word-break I just love it!

Answer (score 0):

Can you use CSS3? If so, try this:

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```

As seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/B93XB/2/